# Как в Django2 отключить csrf валидацию?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Пишу возможность оставлять комментарии на сайте. Делаю все через Ajax. Когда методом POST делаю запрос, Django выдает то, что не передался csrf токен. Как отключить его не во всем проекте, а только для одной вьюхи? (Версия Django: 2.2.1)

Comment: А зачем его отключать в методе POST?

Comment: Просто передавайте csrf-токен в ваших ajax-запросах

Comment: откуда его брать? Как-то генерировать или же из куков?

Comment: @ИбрагимАсеев Вам уже ответили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отключить можно с помощью декоратора [@csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt), но лучше [передавать csrf-токен в ajax-запросе](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: А когда я использую встроенные формы Django, в скрытом input'е добавляется csrf_token. Чем этот токен отличается от токена, который в куках? И какой токен нужно передавать из аджакса, тот который в куках, или его нужно как-то генерировать?

Comment: Это один и тот же токен. В куках токен дублируется для тех случаев, когда ajax-запрос делает без формы.

Comment: Странно, я проверил токены для интереса, они разные